# No Add To Homescreen Pop-up in PWA

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

I Am trying to make a PWA of a static website created using HTML CSS And Javascript. It is working as PWA but the add home screen popup is not appearing in case of Smartphones. But Install button is appearing in Desktop Devices. The code for which is given below:

app.js:

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register("sw.js")
    .then(function (reg) {
      console.log("Successfully registered service worker", reg);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.warn("Error whilst registering service worker", err);
    });
}
```

sw.js:

```
const staticCacheName = "trippyadiveCache";
const assets = [
  "/",
  "/404.html",
  "/allLocations.html",
  "/app.js",
  "/favico.png",
  "/favicon.svg",
  "/favicon.ico",
  "/index.html",
  "/manali.html",
  "/submitBooking.js",
  "/css/bootstrap.css",
  "css/style.css",
  "css/font.css",
  "css/fontawesome-all.css",
];

self.addEventListener("install", (evt) => {
  evt.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then((cache) => {
      console.log("caching cell assets");
      cache.addAll(assets);
    })
  );
});

//activate event
self.addEventListener("activate", (evt) => {
  console.log("service worker activated");
});

//fetch event
self.addEventListener("fetch", (evt) => {
  console.log("fetch Event", evt);
});
```

menifest.webmenifest:

```
{
 "short_name": "Trippyadive",
 "name": "Trippyadive",
 "lang": "en",
 "description": "No Price Hike At Peak Season",
 "start_url": "index.html",
 "background_color": "#ffffff",
 "theme_color": "#ffffff",
 "dir": "ltr",
 "display": "standalone",
 "orientation": "any",
 "prefer_related_applications": "true",
 "icons": [
  {
   "src": "images/icon/android-icon-192x192-dunplab-manifest-26311.png",
   "type": "image/png",
   "sizes": "192x192"
  },
  {
   "src": "/apple-icon-180x180-dunplab-manifest-26311.png",
   "type": "image/png",
   "sizes": "180x180"
  },
  {
   "src": "images/icon/apple-icon-152x152-dunplab-manifest-26311.png",
   "type": "image/png",
   "sizes": "152x152"
  },
  {
   "src": "images/icon/apple-icon-144x144-dunplab-manifest-26311.png",
   "type": "image/png",
   "sizes": "144x144"
  },
  {
   "src": "images/icon/apple-icon-120x120-dunplab-manifest-26311.png",
   "type": "image/png",
   "sizes": "120x120"
  },
  {
   "src": "images/icon/apple-icon-114x114-dunplab-manifest-26311.png",
   "type": "image/png",
   "sizes": "114x114"
  },
  {
   "src": "images/icon/favicon-96x96-dunplab-manifest-26311.png",
   "type": "image/png",
   "sizes": "96x96"
  },
  {
   "src": "images/icon/apple-icon-76x76-dunplab-manifest-26311.png",
   "type": "image/png",
   "sizes": "76x76"
  },
  {
   "src": "images/icon/apple-icon-72x72-dunplab-manifest-26311.png",
   "type": "image/png",
   "sizes": "72x72"
  },
  {
   "src": "images/icon/apple-icon-60x60-dunplab-manifest-26311.png",
   "type": "image/png",
   "sizes": "60x60"
  },
  {
   "src": "images/icon/apple-icon-57x57-dunplab-manifest-26311.png",
   "type": "image/png",
   "sizes": "57x57"
  },
  {
   "src": "images/icon/favicon-32x32-dunplab-manifest-26311.png",
   "type": "image/png",
   "sizes": "32x32"
  },
  {
   "src": "images/icon/favicon-16x16-dunplab-manifest-26311.png",
   "type": "image/png",
   "sizes": "16x16"
  }
 ],
 "prefer_related_applications": "false"
}
```

I would like to know where is my fault and how can I rectify it.

Any kind of help would be appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

PS: You can visit https://www.trippyadive.web.app/ to view it live.

Comment: Add to home screen appears on my android phone, you don't see it until you scroll down a bit.

Comment: Interestingly your SSL has become invalid, that won't help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong.

If you clear your cache and then use the app on your phone ( android / chrome browser) you will see Add to home screen prompt.

I tested on my phone , and I get the prompt.

Comment: Can you share your phone and browser info? Also you need to interact with the website in a certain way before you will get the prompt. I will say , open the url , interact for atleast 5 seconds, close the tab, then open url again

Comment: I am using Nokia 5.1 Plus and Browser is Chrome Version 87.0.4280.101

Comment: I believe this to be your local system issue. If you have any other phone lying around then test on it.

Comment: Yes May Be I Have Some Local Issue. Its working fine on other devices